# How to add top item in list view?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Basically I want a list view(CheckBox and TextView) that has all the data from a database but the first item in the view always being "ALL".I have done loading listadapter but i don't know how to add first row as All.
If I am clicking All checkebox.I want to other checkbox's state as false.
my code as follow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do it like this?

You get position in `getview()`, then for the first item add condition. Something like this:

```
if(position == 0)


    youTextView.setText("All");
```

That's it.

Comment: I was try the above method.but It will override the position 0.the list first item override.how to start first position in list view

Answer (score 1):

you can add **HeaderView** in **ListView**

here is simple code of **How to add HeaderView in ListView.**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout listHeaderView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.headerview, null);
ListView.addHeaderView(listHeaderView);
```

create **headerview.xml** and you can add in this layout **TextView** with **"ALL"** text.